# Conditional required in jsf 2 when FacesConverter involved

Tags: validation, jsf-2

I have a form like this:

```
<h:form>
    Phone number:
            <h:inputText id="phone_number"
                         value="#{dbUserManager.phoneNumber}"
                         validatorMessage="The phone number is invalid."
                         required="#{auth.value eq 'MOBILE'}"
                         requiredMessage="Phone number is required." />
            </h:inputText>
    Authentication type:
            <h:selectOneMenu  value="#{dbUserManager.authentication}" converter="#{authenticationTypeConverter}"  binding="#{auth}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{dbUserManager.authTypeList}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

AuthenticationType is an entity similar to this:

```
@Entity
public class AuthenticationType implements Serializable 
{
  @Id
  @Basic(optional = false)
  private Short id;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  private String description;
  @Override

  //...

  public String toString() 
  {
    return description;
  }
```

and finally AuthenticationTypeConverter:

```
@Stateless
@ManagedBean
@FacesConverter(value="authenticationTypesConverter")
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class AuthenticationTypeConverter implements Converter
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="pu")
    private EntityManager em = null;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String string)
    {
        TypedQuery<AuthenticationType> q = em.createNamedQuery(
                AuthenticationType.FIND_BY_DESCRIPTION,
                AuthenticationType.class);
        q.setParameter("description", string);
        return q.getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o)
    {
        if (o == null)
        {
            return "";
        }
        return o.toString();
    }
}
```

What I tried to do is that to set the required of phone number to true when authentication type is set to 'MOBILE'. But it's not behaving as I expect.

I think the problem lies in the fact that I need to use FacesConverter for AuthenticationType. But I don't know how to solve it.

Can anyone give a hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rerender the `h:inputText`-field after the user chose from your `h:selectOneMenu`. To do so, change this selection to

```
<h:selectOneMenu  value="#{dbUserManager.authentication}" 
     converter="#{authenticationTypeConverter}"  binding="#{auth}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{dbUserManager.authTypeList}" />
    <f:ajax event="change" render="phone_number" />
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Also in the inputTexts `required`-attribute I would expect something more like

```
{dbUserManager.authentication.description}
```

Give it a try...

*Update 2014/01/22:*

If you want to hold already typed informations in the `phone_number` field, you can tell the `<f:ajax>` tag to execute not only `selectOneMenu` but also the input field before rendering it new. In this case replace the upper `<f:ajax />` solution with

```
...
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this phone_number" render="phone_number" />
...
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I did so, and I got this error: event="itemSelect" event it is not a valid eventName defined for this component

Comment: Sorry, mixed it up with another select-component. Answer corrected now.

Comment: is it possible to render the a component but keep the value?

Comment: Try to extend the f:ajax to: `<f:ajax event="change" execute="@this phone_number" render="phone_number" />` ... see also updated answer.

Comment: Thanks it solved by just using ajax on authentication type like <f:ajax />